# How can I modify the Civilization IV keyboard commands on OS X?

Tags: civilization-4, keyboard, macos

I play on a MacBook Pro, so I have no number pad.  Ideally I'd love to be able to play completely keyboard based, with movement keys similar to 'vi' (`hjkl`, etc).

I really want to be able to natively edit the key bindings that execute in-game, not run os level software.

Answer (score 2):

I think [keyremap4macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) might help you. It can enable a number pad. It's how i played civIV. I believe, you just need to press the fn pressing the "numpad" keys.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Civilization so I can't confirm this but holding the `fn` key (bottom left of the keyboard on a MacBook Pro) causes the keys around the right hand home-row to work like a number pad. These keys have the numpad key they correspond to in the bottom right corner of the key. For example `fn`+`M`=`num0`, `fn`+`L`=`num3`, `fn`+`U`=`num4`

I'm not familiar with keyboard shortcuts in Civ IV so there may be some negative overlap (`7`, `8` & `9` are the same key for the numpad and top row numbers) and pressing the `fn` key can be a little awkward but this should at least let you use numpad controls.